# Is there a way to return JSON on ALB lambda?

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-elb

I have created lambda function on node.js which returns JSON.

It connected with API Gateway and worked well.

I want to connect it to amazon load balancer.

I tried it but it returns HTML page.

```
async function run(event)
{

    let ret = {};

    ret = {
       'statusCode': 200,
       'statusDescription': '200 OK',
       'headers': {
           'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
    }
    ret.code = 200;
    return ret;
}

exports.handler = run;
```

How to return JSON?

Comment: How did you connect lambda function to load balancer? what end point you are calling when you get HTML back?

Comment: It returns blank page. I didn't use 'JSON.stringify' for JSON

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a stringified body attribute to the response

```
async function run(event)
{

    let ret = {};

    ret = {
       'statusCode': 200,
       'statusDescription': '200 OK',
       'headers': {
           'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        'body': JSON.stringify({
            test: 1
        })
    }
    ret.code = 200;
    return ret;
}

exports.handler = run;
```